# Has Sony spoiled the endings of the Amazing Spider-man films?

Tags: the-amazing-spider-man

Sony recently announced that a [Sinister Six](http://screenrant.com/venom-movie-amazing-spider-man-sinister-six-sony/)  film is to be released in 2015. So does that mean the villains in the Amazing Spider-man sequels all survive?

Comment: On the side note, its sony who take decision on Spider-man films rather then Marvel/Disney.

Comment: For a comic-fan its very usual. Comic fan always know that Norman Osborn is not going to completely die in Spider-man film and it proved right when his glimpses appears in Spider-man 2. Similarly fans know that Loki is not going to die in Thor 1 or Avenger or Thor 2. Some main character not dies that easy because they have served better purpose in comics and can be useful in later stories. So i don't think anything is ruined at all. Its a different fact that, Fox and Sony is a good source for ruining film franchises.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's a good question.

Even though this news does imply that the villains from the new movies will survive to appear in their own spin-off, it's worth knowing that there have been several different line-ups for the Sinister Six over the years - see [this marvel Wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinister_Six) for more details.

It is entirely possible that Sony could introduce a new member should one fall by the wayside, however, considering the recent Hollywood predilection for setting up big ensemble pictures, I wouldn't be surprised in the least to see every baddie survive the three Spider-Man films.

Comment: curious whats your dp? is that a cat spider?

Comment: LOL - yep. It worked better than my last avatar when the winter hats were in effect :)

Answer (score 8):

[No one really dies in comic books](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comic_book_death). Least of all villains. They are always defeated, but always return again - either by miraculously surviving, having their name and mantle taken up by a family member of protege, or any other plot twist to return a fan favorite character to the page.

While this tradition isn't as noticeable in superhero *movies*, mostly because there are far fewer movies than there are comic-book stories, I still think it's the it's a part of the genre: bad guys are *defeated*, not *killed*.

Given that particular genre trope, I don't think a film focusing on a group of recurring villains from previous movies can be considered a *spoiler*. Recurring villains are a part of the genre, not a plot spoiler.

Comment: No one really dies in comic books except uncle ben.

Comment: I agree with your comments, but wouldn't it be better served to answer this in the sense of the MCU and not the comic book universe?

Comment: @AnkitSharma And he dies EVERY SINGLE TIME.

Comment: @Paulster2 Mcu is like a same alien-vesre to Spider-man franchise as Comics.

Comment: @AnkitSharma ... Point taken :D